# There are producer issues with spring cloud stream 3.0

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I read about the spring cloud stream 3.0 documents, to understand the new using java.util.function.[Supplier/Function/Consumer] to represent the producers, the consumption and production, consumers, and this should be correct.

But I don't understand Supplier.

The documentation states that polling for suppliers is used to consistently generate data for suppliers, and no program involvement is required.

But many times, we need to generate a data at a specific time, such as a web request, and I can't find any documentation or examples for that.

It might be as simple as injecting the Supplier object and calling the get() method, but how do you disable the polling call?

Thanks to all who provided the information.

Comment: There is a problem with getting my understanding of the three objects: Supplier, which is generating data continuously; Function, which is taking arguments from the program and producing data; and Consumer, which is consuming data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We'll update the documentation for SR1 which we'll release in few weeks, but here is the full code demonstrating how you can accomplish what you're describing. We rely on EmitterProcessor from project reactor:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Controller
public class WebSourceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebSourceApplication.class);
    }

    EmitterProcessor<String> processor = EmitterProcessor.create();

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void delegateToSupplier(@RequestBody String body) {
        System.out.println("Sending " + body);
        processor.onNext(body);
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<String>> supplier() {
        return () -> processor;
    }
}
```

and then `and then curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" localhost:8080/ -d Hello`

Comment: Does that mean that the EmitterProcessor object needs to be Shared in the application for operations?There is a view in the document, produce a Flux, polling will not take effect, is that right?

Comment: Turning an EmitterProcessor into a Flux or Mono, are they consistent?

Comment: @hero-zh Yes they are consistent: `EmitterProcessor` extends a `Flux`. I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59099369/how-to-configure-the-bindings-of-a-function-in-spring-cloud-stream-to-bind-its-i/59149580#59149580) and this answer gave me the details to formulate my own. I built an reusable solution with these details and a fully working demo that you can find [here](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-59099369)

Comment: I just wanted to add that if you are using kotlin, simply converting this example to kotlin does not work (while the Function and Consumer seem fine).  I spent some time and then finally converted this back to java and it worked like magic.  I'm not sure if there's a kotlin/lambda version out there.

Comment: Kotlin Version. To send a message from a different class, auto-wire emitter processor bean and call onNext method.
```
@Bean
 fun emitterProcessor(): EmitterProcessor<String>{
  return EmitterProcessor.create<String>()
 }


 @Bean
 open fun dataSupplier() : (Flux<String>) -> Flux<String>{

  return {
   emitterProcessor()
  }

 }
```

Comment: Is there support for KStreams? I'm using KStreams with Spring Cloud Function and a Suplier with Flux<String> didn't get recognized as a Kafka topic. I need to return a Function<KStream, KStream> from the bean for it to publish to Kafka, and it's not working with Emitter

Comment: EmitterProcessor is deprecated now. What's an alternative to that?

Comment: `StreamBridge.send(..)` - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_sending_arbitrary_data_to_an_output_e_g_foreign_event_driven_sources