# Alternative to StreamBridge

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, spring-cloud-function

My Requirement in completely same as what is described here [There are producer issues with spring cloud stream 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135268/there-are-producer-issues-with-spring-cloud-stream-3-0) by @hero-zh

I found that @Oleg Zhurakousky is suggesting to use StremBridge but when i looked into the class there is @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") added at class level.
Which means this class is soon going to be deprecated.

I am looking for an alternative of StreamBridge which i can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `@SuppressWarnings` means that we just wanted to suppress warnings since StreamBridge itself is using some of the deprecated components. StreamBridge itself is not deprecated and in fact is a new component meant to replace deprecated components. So please feel safe to use it.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I have implemented the streamBridge as an alternative and it worked.

Comment: Hi @nitin737 Could you please help me with a sample code, I am trying to make the StreamBridge work. The StreamBridge is not reading the producer configuration. Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi @nafi ,
Please follow this medium post
https://nitin737.medium.com/publish-kafka-events-using-streambridge-in-spring-boot-alternative-to-messagechannelfactory-1bacc2075bca

i have put the code required here. This is a working code i can share the github link also if you need.